# Windows Server 2012 Change Password Without Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-server, windows-server-2012

We are using a Windows Server 2012 box to host a QlikView server. Users access a QlikView portal via their web browser, and never need to login to the actual windows box, however they are authenticated by their windows username and password.

I have created random passwords for every user but I would like to allow users to change these **without** needing to login to the actual box remote. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: First search for any programmatic remote administration problem should usually be WMI + whatever you're trying to do. WMI Change Password brings up lots of likely results.

Comment: Thanks looks promising, had never heard of WMI before.